# django form wizard with file upload multiple not working

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I am currently digging into django form wizards and I am trying to upload multiple images. Unfortunately, the BaseStorage provided by django form wizard does not handle multiple files. It always assumes a dictionary to be passed. There is a fix posted [here](https://github.com/django/django-formtools/issues/98?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container).

The problem is now, that the posted code breaks in the render_done step of the form wizard when the form_obj is reevaluated. FileFields do not validate when the file is turned from dict to a list.

Can anybody point me in the correct direction on how to fix this?

How do generic views deal with this issue? Or don't they have this issue at all?